# How do you get the first and second word of a sentence in PHP?

Tags: php, html

Welcome
Is this code correct? I actually get the first and second words. Is this correct?

```
$sentence = 'Is this code correct? I actually get the first and second words. Is this correct';
$abbreviation = implode(" ", array_slice(explode(' ', $sentence), 0, 2));
 
$url = sprintf("xxx", urlencode($abbreviation));


$json = file_get_contents($url);

$results = json_decode($json);

foreach($results[1] as $result)
{
    // echo search suggestion
     
echo '<h2>' .$result[0]. ' </h2><br>';
}
```

What I want to do is attach the topic title in place of these words
`Is this code correct? I actually get the first and second words. Is this correct`
This is the address function
 `echo $titles;`
Can you help me

No attempt was successful. An error occurs if the title function is set to `<?php echo $titles; ?>`

Comment: @druvi-shah  Hello, it didn't work for me. I want to enter this title ( <?php echo $titles; ?> ) inside this episode so that the title can be read from the episode itself
Example of what I want to do ( $sentence = '<?php echo $titles; ?>'; )

Answer (score -1):

```
$sentence = 'Is this code correct? I actually get the first and second words. Is this correct?';
$words = explode(' ', $sentence);
$firstWord = $words[0];
$secondWord = $words[1];

$abbreviation = $firstWord . ' ' . $secondWord;
$url = sprintf("xxx", urlencode($abbreviation));

$json = file_get_contents($url);
$results = json_decode($json);

$titles = $results[0]->title;

$modifiedSentence = str_replace($abbreviation, $titles, $sentence);

echo $modifiedSentence;
```

Comment: Please post an explanation of what you changed instead of just dumping code. What was the issue with OP's code?

Comment: add this 4 line of code : 

$words = explode(' ', $sentence);
$firstWord = $words[0];
$secondWord = $words[1];
$abbreviation = $firstWord . ' ' . $secondWord;

Comment: instead of foreach loop change : $titles = $results[0]->title;
$modifiedSentence = str_replace($abbreviation, $titles, $sentence);
echo $modifiedSentence;